# HOw to convert following data in object in JS

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, python-3.x, javascript-objects

```
"[{'id': 3, 'Name': 'ABC', 'price': [955, 1032, 998, 941, 915, 952, 899]}, {'id': 4, 'Name': 'XYZ', 'id': [ 1016, 1015, 1014, 915, 1023, 1012, 998, 907, 952, 945, 1013, 1057, 1018, 899]}]"
```

I'm trying to convert the above python list of dict. into an object in js but I'm getting an error. JS code as follow:

```
var check_data;
check_data = $('#vendor_dict').val();
check_data=JSON.parse(check_data);
```

Error :

```
VM82:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Answer (score 3):

JSON has very strict requirements about how values are to be expressed, your issue is that the string data has single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` as per requirements. In order to successfully parse it using the native `JSON.parse` implementation, you need to fix that, for instance by manually replacing the quotes

```js
const data = `[{'id': 3, 'Name': 'ABC', 'price': [955, 1032, 998, 941, 915, 952, 899]}, {'id': 4, 'Name': 'XYZ', 'id': [ 1016, 1015, 1014, 915, 1023, 1012, 998, 907, 952, 945, 1013, 1057, 1018, 899]}]`

console.log(JSON.parse(data.replace(/'/g, '"')))
```

Instead of manually replacing the quotes you could also try using JSON5 for parsing, which is a less restricting version of the parser

```js
const data = `[{'id': 3, 'Name': 'ABC', 'price': [955, 1032, 998, 941, 915, 952, 899]}, {'id': 4, 'Name': 'XYZ', 'id': [ 1016, 1015, 1014, 915, 1023, 1012, 998, 907, 952, 945, 1013, 1057, 1018, 899]}]`

console.log(JSON5.parse(data))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json5/0.5.1/json5.min.js"></script>
```

Personally I recommend usage of JSON5 because in some edge cases the first method may fail. For your data in particular there does not seem to be any issues with doing it both ways however for data containing escaped single quotes or unescaped double quotes it can fail. For example:

```js
const data = `{'a': 'test "test" test'}`
const data2 = `{'a': 'test \' test'}`

try {
  JSON.parse(data.replace(/'/g, '"'))
}
catch (e) {
  console.error(e)
}

try {
  JSON.parse(data2.replace(/'/g, '"'))
}
catch (e) {
  console.error(e)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert to JSON in python just use json library. It produces nice looking JSON object:

```
import json
print(json.dumps([{'id': 3, 'Name': 'ABC', 'price': [955, 1032, 998, 941, 915, 952, 899]}, {'id': 4, 'Name': 'XYZ', 'id': [ 1016, 1015, 1014, 915, 1023, 1012, 998, 907, 952, 945, 1013, 1057, 1018, 899]}]))
```

Take a look at the https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html